# How to create a column for checkbox in Postgres table?

Tags: postgresql, jsp, checkbox

I want to create a table in **postgres db**. I use jdbc driver to connect to it by **jsp application**.

One of my column is a checkbox. 
I do no what type it should be declared while creating a table.
After creating what values i should insert in it.

I have two columns

| shop    | closed |

Answer (score 3):

A "check box" in a PostgreSQL table would be represented by a `boolean` data type with a `NOT NULL` constraint. Some applications might use an `integer` column instead, but that's not as good.

How to make it into a "check box" depends entirely on the application that's talking to PostgreSQL. Your tags mention JSP, so you're probably talking to PostgreSQL via some kind of ORM layer like Hibernate that translates the database access into Java objects, in which case it'll just be a java `bool`. If not, then you'd use SQL via JDBC to access the `Boolean` value.

Comment: Or it could be a row in a child table. The presence of which indicates checkedness. Depends how many checkboxes you have and how often they need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should create bit or boolean column and insert into it 1 or 0 at the time of inserting.